# ListLinePlot Shifts, Does Not Plot Initial Condition

Tags: plotting

The code I've written generates a recurrence table correctly, but when plotting the output table there is data missing and "k-axis (horizontal axis)" values are right-shifted in ListPlot and ListLinePlot. I also want to see the (0,0) tick mark but that does also not show. The initial condition (0,0.1) is missing from the both plots. Any advice is most welcomed.

```
Clear[r, y0, k, NN]
r = 3.5; y0 = 0.1; NN = 10;
N[TableForm[ 
  MapThread[
   Prepend, {RecurrenceTable[{ y[k + 1] == r* y[k]*(1 - y[k]), 
      y[0] == y0}, { y}, {k, 0, NN}], Range[0, NN]}], 
  TableHeadings -> {{}, {"k", " y[k]"}}]]

sol = RecurrenceTable[{y[k + 1] == r*y[k]*(1 - y[k]), y[0] == y0}, 
   y, {k, 0, NN}];
ListPlot[sol, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.021]}];
ListLinePlot[sol, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thin, Red}, PointSize[0.021]}]
```

Comment: `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}`?

Comment: I've tried that -- didn't show

Comment: does it do what you want if you add `DataRange -> {0, NN}` ?

Comment: AxesOrigin->{-1,0} shows the 0 on the horizontal

Comment: I had to do DataRange->{-1,0} for it to work